# Can't add to variable

Tags: javascript

so I have problem with basics cause my variable when i add 1 or just increment gives back nan I don't really know if it's problem with saving or it just can't add. here is code that contains that variable

```js
let add;

if(localStorage.getItem("add")>=1){
    add=localStorage.getItem("add");
  }
  else {
    add = 1;
    localStorage.setItem("add", add);
  }
  
  function oncl(){

add = add++;
 localStorage.setItem("add",add);

}
```

Comment: are you aware you can just use `localStorage.add = localStorage.add || 1` and `localStorage.add++`

Comment: if you do ++ it will only work on a number. Not a string of a number, otherwise you get NaN

Answer (score 0):

nan means it is not a number because localStorage.getItem() returns a string not a number so you need to parse it into a number first then you can do numbers operations

if you are using integers use

```
parseInt(localStorage.getItem("add")) 
//you can also use parseFloat() or Number()
```